# Sketching these values as an Argand diagram describe in words where on the diagram all of the roots lie.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've calculated $i^{i\pi}=e^{-\pi  (\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}$ for different values of k, I just don't understand how I would plot these, I'm assuming there all on the real axis as there's no imaginary part, however I'm unsure. What should the diagram look like?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the periodicity of complex exponentials, there are multiple answers to the above equation.
Start by rewriting the problem with e as the base:$$i^{i\pi}=e^{i\pi log(i)}$$

Recall that: $$e^{i\pi/2+2n\pi}=isin(\pi/2+2n\pi)+cos(\pi/2+2n\pi)=i$$

So $$i^{i\pi}=e^{i\pi(i\pi/2+2n\pi)}=e^{-\pi^2/2+2in\pi^2}$$ where $n\in\Bbb Z$

Let $n=ik$ such that $$e^{-\pi^2/2+2i(ik)\pi^2}=e^{-\pi(\pi/2+2k\pi)}$$
Then $$k=-i n$$

Comment: I've already arrived at that solution I just don't know what the plot would look like

Comment: I dont really know what you mean in terms of a plot. Since the k values are just the negative integers multiplied by i, the plot should have the k values such that $k\in-i\Bbb Z$.

Comment: There should be a way, do they represent a unit circle ?

Comment: They just lie on the negative imaginary axis. I dont believe theres anything else unique about the k values. A unit circle would be values generated by $e^i\theta$.

Comment: How do they lie on the imaginary axis ? And shouldn't it be the positive axis as $e^-r> 0, \forall r $